# $form_state->setErrorByName() for a form in a block doesn't work properly

Tags: forms, 8, blocks

I created a very simple module 'testform'. In this module, I generate a form and a block. (via the drush console)

The form contains a textfield ("housename") and a submit button.

In the form Class, I add a condition in the validate handler for display an error when the user submit the form without any data in the textfield.

#### The form from the form page (no problem)

1. I load the form page (url path found in the testform.routing.yml)
2. I click to the submit button without enter any data in the housename textfield
3. The next page load, the empty housename field is red and **there is an error message "the housename field is empty"** 
   => By this way, all is ok

[image]

#### The form from the block (there is the problem)

1. I load a page where is displayed the form block
2. In the block, I click to the sumbit button without enter any data in the textfield
3. The next page load, the empty housename field is red and **there *isn't* any error message**

[image]

4. If I reload the page, the setError message appears

I don't understand why when the form is displayed in a block, the error message doesn't work properly.

This is the code I am using.

#### The modules/custom/testform/src/Form/DefaultForm.php file

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\testform\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Class DefaultForm.
 *
 * @package Drupal\testform\Form
 */
class DefaultForm extends FormBase {


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'default_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['housename'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('housename'),
      '#maxlength' => 64,
      '#size' => 64,
    ];

    $form['submit'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $housename = $form_state->getValue('housename');
    if(empty($housename)){
      $form_state->setErrorByName("housename","The housename field is empty");
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Display result.
    ksm("Work...");

  }

}
```

#### The modules/custom/testform/src/Plugin/Block/DefaultBlock.php file

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\testform\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides a 'DefaultBlock' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *  id = "default_block",
 *  admin_label = @Translation("Default block"),
 * )
 */
class DefaultBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    return \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\testform\Form\DefaultForm');

  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2649746). You can see the same problem with the core user login block upon submitting bad credentials. The comments in that issue note that it's a side effect of [another issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2537732) which has a fix committed to the 8.2.x branch.